# Multiple LINQ expressions, and dynamic properties

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics, expression

1.) I have an entity query like: `return myEntityStore.Query<theType>(x => x.Name == "whatevs");`

However, ideally I want to call a function which appends other expressions to the original query, like OrderBy's and more Where's.

Something like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> ProcessQuery<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> theOriginalQuery) where T: class
    {
        return EntityStore.Query<T>(theOriginalQuery).Where(x => x.Active == true).OrderBy(x => x.OrderBy);
    }
```

2.) One of the obvious problems here is that I'm working with `<T>`, so is there a way to specify the property as a string or something?

```
<T>(expression).OrderBy(x => "x.ThisColumnExistsIPromise");
```

3.) The Query function already transforms the expression into a Where(), so would it be sufficient to simply do a Where(expression).Where(expression)?

So, at the end of the day, is the below possible to achieve?

```
entityStore.Query<T>(originalExpression).Where(additionalExpression).Where(x => "x.Active == true").OrderBy(x => "x.OrderBy");
```

Comment: As you might have guessed, our schema standards force every table to have an 'Active' and 'OrderBy' column.

Comment: Have you considered implementing an interface on each type with these two properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the question isn't so clear. But I noticed that your problem might be solved if you used **[LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx)** then you could use **Property name as string** to do whatever you want *(OrderBy, Where ....)*

For more information look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)